# Save time ranges with dates based on data set time blocks in java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, arraylist, data-transform

I need to convert an ArrayList set of data into another ArrayList set of data. I need to convert "Original data" into "Needed result" below. Basically, I have time blocks of dates and times and need to see which data sets fall within the same time range on the same date and save it. Algorithms are really are not my strong suit unfortunately. Have any ideas?

Dates are strings. Sorry if I didnt clarify before.

```
selectedTimeSlotTracker data:

{
("2020-03-04",4,"10:00", "10:30"),
("2020-03-04",5,"10:30", "11:00"),
("2020-03-04",8,"12:00", "12:30"),
("2020-03-04",9,"12:30", "13:00"),
("2020-03-05",8,"12:00", "12:30"),
("2020-03-05",9,"12:30", "13:00")
}


summaryObjects:


{
("2020-03-04","10:00", "11:00"),
("2020-03-04","12:00", "13:00"),
("2020-03-05","12:00", "13:00")
}
```

```
private void transformSelectedToSummaryObjects(){
        summaryObjects.clear();

        int indexOfSummaryObjects = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedTimeSlotTracker.size(); i++ ){

            summaryObjects.add(new SummaryObject(selectedTimeSlotTracker.get(i).getDate(), selectedTimeSlotTracker.get(i).getStartTIme(), selectedTimeSlotTracker.get(i).getEndTime()));

            for (int j = i; j < selectedTimeSlotTracker.size()-1; j++){

                if (selectedTimeSlotTracker.get(j).getDate().equals(selectedTimeSlotTracker.get(j+1).getDate())){

                    if(selectedTimeSlotTracker.get(j).getEndTime().equals(selectedTimeSlotTracker.get(j+1).getStartTIme())) {

                        summaryObjects.get(indexOfSummaryObjects).setEndTime(selectedTimeSlotTracker.get(j+1).getEndTime());

                        i = j + 1;
                    }
                }

            }
            indexOfSummaryObjects++;


        }




        courtReservationSummaryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

This is my attempt. Unfortunately, it doesnt create clean breaks and just lumps end times from different dates into the same date.

Below is the data set im getting with my method for summaryObjects arraylist which is wrong.

```
{(2020-03-04,"10:00", "13:00")}
```

Will post more information when I get back in a few.

Comment: This looks like a home work question. I recommend you post the code for some attempt.

Comment: So if the date and end time of one element equal the date and start time of the subsequent one, join the two into one — and remember to consider whether it can be joined with further elements — is that it? It doesn’t sound too hard for an experienced programmer, so maybe you can explain more where your trouble is, where you get stuck?

Comment: Sorry, i know it does but I promise it isn't. Its for an app. I am basically making a piece within an app for scheduling based on the user picking time blocks within a day view. They can also switch dates within that and that's why the dataset has multiple dates. The original is the dataset I have after the user picks their times etc..  Just really drawing a blank trying to get the conversion right so I can display a summary of their times selected before confirmation of appointments

Comment: Even if you can't figure out how to do it, you need to explain what the requirements are. I guessed the same thing that Ole V.V. did, but we are just guessing.

Comment: Yeah I'll be back in a few and post what I tried before and all the specs in a short while. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Parse your date portion as a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2020-03-04" ) ;
```

Parse your time-of-day values as a `LocalTime`.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "10:00" ) ;
```

Join them to make a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt ) ;
```

Compare your `LocalDateTime` objects by calling `isEqual`, `isBefore`, and `isAfter`. Tip: A shorter way of asking "Is this date-time equal to or after the other date-time?" is to ask "Is this date-time *not* before the other date-time?".

You should be able to work out the rest of the logic. Understand that *java.time* classes use [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So you will be creating new instances, not modifying existing objects. Search Stack Overflow to learn more, as this has all been handled many already.

You might even want to write your own little class to represent the span-of-time with a pair of `LocalDateTime` objects, named something like `LocalDateTimeSpan`. For inspiration, look at the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library, and its `Interval` & `LocalDateRange` classes.